# Crear datatable vacia

Tags: php, datatables

Tengo el siguiente código html

```
<table id="tabla"></table>
```

Y en JS quiero inicializar un datatable vacío, para luego después rellenar la tabla.

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
   $table = $('#tabla').DataTable();
});
```

El problema es que me está dando este error en la consola

> Uncaught TypeError: c[h[n][0]] is undefined

en el fichero jquery.datatables.min.js

¿Por que no puedo crear un datatable vacío?

Saludos

Comment: Hola Thenine, no estoy seguro, pero diría que mínimo deberías indicar las columnas que va a tener.

Answer (score 0):

La [Documentación oficial te indica como puedes crear un Datatable vacío](https://datatables.net/extensions/searchpanes/examples/advanced/emptyDataSet.html)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        dom: 'Plfrtip',
        language: {
            searchPanes: {
                emptyPanes: 'There are no panes to display. :/'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.7.0/css/select.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/searchpanes/2.2.0/css/searchPanes.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/searchpanes/2.2.0/js/dataTables.searchPanes.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.7.0/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>


<table id="example" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```